# Object Orientation messed up after conversion from USDZ to OBJ

Tags: 3d, projection-matrices

I am using the following code to reconstruct usdz (apple 3d) object to obj files.

```
// Extension to transform SCNGeometry with a matrix
extension SCNGeometry {
    func applyingTransform(_ transform: SCNMatrix4) -> SCNGeometry {
        let vertexSources = sources(for: .vertex)
        guard let vertexSource = vertexSources.first else { return self }
        
        var vertices = [SCNVector3](repeating: SCNVector3Zero, count: vertexSource.vectorCount)
        vertexSource.data.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
            for i in 0..<vertexSource.vectorCount {
                let ptr = buffer.baseAddress!.advanced(by: i * vertexSource.dataStride)
                vertices[i] = ptr.load(as: SCNVector3.self)
                vertices[i] = SCNVector3FromGLKVector3(GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(SCNMatrix4ToGLKMatrix4(transform), SCNVector3ToGLKVector3(vertices[i])))
            }
        }
        
        let newGeometrySource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
        return SCNGeometry(sources: [newGeometrySource], elements: self.elements)
    }
}

// Function to recursively export nodes, applying transformations
private func exportNode(_ node: SCNNode, to asset: MDLAsset, applying worldTransform: SCNMatrix4 = SCNMatrix4Identity) {
    let localTransform = node.transform
    let combinedTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(localTransform, worldTransform)
    
    if let geometry = node.geometry {
        let transformedGeometry = geometry.applyingTransform(combinedTransform)
        if let mdlMesh = MDLMesh(scnGeometry: transformedGeometry) {
            asset.add(mdlMesh)
        }
    }
    
    for childNode in node.childNodes {
        exportNode(childNode, to: asset, applying: combinedTransform)
    }
}
```

However in the results I see that all the objects are centered at origin. I think this is an issue with the matrices and it is losing all the translations when recreating vertices in obj. Any insights will be helpful on how I can tackle this. Also, not sure if this is an issue with the matrices as this is my guess. [Messed up 3D objects after recreation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8PHT.png)